# How to embed discrete IDs in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

There are many discrete IDs and I want to embed them to feed into a neural network. `tf.nn.embedding_lookup` only supports the fixed range of IDs, i.e., ID from 0 to N. How to embed the discrete IDs with the range of 0 to `2^62`.

Comment: I'm also facing the exact issue, my IDs are also on order of 2^62, for which I wan to build embeddings. I'm hesitant to build a custom lookup table as suggested in the answer, as I feel there should be a decent solution already to this problem. Have you figured the right solution yet @cstur4 ?

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify how I understand your question, you want to do something like word embeddings, but instead of words you want to use discrete IDs (not indices). Your IDs can be very large (2^62). But the number of distinct IDs is much less.

If we were to process words, then we would build a dictionary of the words and feed the indices within the dictionary to the neural network (into the embedding layer). That is basically what you need to do with your discrete IDs too. Usually you'd also reserve one number (such as `0`) for not previously seen values. You could also later trim the dictionary to only include the most frequent values and put all others into the same *unknown* bucket (exactly the same options you would have when doing word embeddings or other nlp).

e.g.:

- *unknown* -> 0
- 84588271 -> 1
- 92238356 -> 2
- 78723958 -> 3

Comment: Is it possible to avoid any remapping operation? It is expensive to do this operation in the large dataset.

Comment: What does large mean here? I am not aware of any alternative. The model itself can use embedding, but you need a stable dictionary first and to build that you have to go through your dataset at least once. That shouldn't be very expensive in comparison to the training. You could also consider https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/lookup/HashTable. But if performance is the primary concern, then you would do the mapping once ahead of time as you would usually show the same data to the model multiple times. As said, I don't think this will be your bottleneck.

Comment: I want to do online learning in the feature and the hashtable is un-friendly to the unseen instances.